# Align \coloneqq and =

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

One thing that has infuriated me for a long time is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        x &\coloneqq a^2 + b^2\\
        &= c^2
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

I just want to introduce a definition and then proceed with a calculation. But it looks horrible:

[image]

The `\coloneqq` and = are not aligned on the right hand side, and the formulas following are neither.

(Note: Putting the `&` on the other side of the equations gives the correct alignment, but the wrong spacing to the formulas on the right hand side)

Comment: By the way, `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so you don't have to load both.

Comment: And about the tag, tags without questions are deleted every day ([I accidentally created a tag. How do I delete it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71123)), so don't worry about that.

Comment: I have a simpler solution: avoiding ≔ `;-)`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since `align` right-aligns the first field and left aligns the second, one must place the `\coloneqq` and subsequent `=` in the first `align` field so that they get right aligned.

However, `align` is set up to provide proper `\mathrel` spacing for `&=` constructs, but not `=&` constructs.  Thus, in addition to placing `\coloneqq` and subsequent `=` at the end of the first `align` field of their respective rows, they must be suffixed with an empty `{}` placeholder prior to the `&` separator, so that the `\mathrel` character of these two symbols can be forced to provide the proper spacing following the symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        x \coloneqq{}& a^2 + b^2\\
        ={}& c^2
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My life was futile without this. Thank you.

Comment: @Turion THe `{}` placeholder on one, the other, or both side(s) of a `\mathrel` object tells the `\mathrel` object to provide spacing *as if* something were there.

Comment: Then I wonder why no `{}` is needed when we put the `&` on the other side.

Comment: @Turion the `align` environment is designed to "catch" the case where the `=` follows the `&` and insert space appropriately.  It is not set up for the case where the `=` precedes the `&` and thus, for this case, the `{}` must be added manually.

Comment: @Turion `{}` is automatically added at the beginning of the cell.

Comment: is there also a way to have `\coloneqq`, `=`, and `\eqqcolon` aligned in the same `align`?

Comment: @pseyfert That is problematic for several reasons.  In particular, if you desire to have the `=` portion of all those symbols line up, then you will be forced to accept one of 2 undesirable outcomes: 1)  non-standard spacing to the surrounding math atoms; or 2) non-aligned math atoms to either side of these symbols.

Answer (score 5):

Another simple solution with the very small package `makebox`, which puts its second argument in a box of the first argument width:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makebox}

\begin{document}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\begin{align}
  x &\coloneqq a^2 + b^2\\
  &\mathrel{\makebox*{$\coloneqq$}{\hfill$=$}} c^2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is the definition of `\coloneqq`:

```
> \coloneqq=macro:
->\vcentcolon \mathrel {\mkern -1.2mu}=
```

We can place whatever precedes `=` inside `\phantom`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  x &\coloneqq a^2 + b^2\\
  &\phantom{\vcentcolon\mathrel{\mkern-1.2mu}}= c^2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```